# WCF KnownType Inputs Entity Framework

Tags: c#, wcf

I am trying to design a webservice that use the Knowntype attribute for the Derived class.

The reason i am using the knowtype is to have a single endpoint for all derived classes.

```
[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(Derived))]
[KnownType(typeof(DerivedTwo))]
//And other derived types
class Base 
{
  string Name {get; set;}
}
[DataContract]
class Derived :Base
{
 string WorkedOn {get; set;}
}
[DataContract]
class DerivedTwo :Base
{
 string CompletedOn {get; set;}
}

public class TestContext :DbContext
{
  //ctor of context 

  public Dbset<Base> Base {get; set;}
  public Dbset<Derived> Base {get; set;}
}

public class Repository<T> where T:Base 
    {
        private readonly TestContext _testContext;
        public Repository()
        {
            _testContext = new TestContext();
        }

        public void Add(T input)
        {
           var kew =  _testContext.Set<T>().Add(input);
        }

        public void Save()
        {
            _testContext.SaveChanges();
        }  
}

public Interface IService 
{
  [OperationContract]
  void Add(Base base);
}

public class Service :IService
{
   public void Add(Base base)
   {
     var repository = new Repository<typeof(base)>();
     repository.Add(base);
     repository.Save();
   }
}
```

When the client calls this endpoint and passes a derived class 
i want a entry to be added to the derived class table (TPC -- table for concrete class) 
Is this even possible??? 
what are my potions to design a webservice like this.

**Edited to answer**

---

I am pretty new i do not know where i am supposed reply and the edit time for the comment below expired so i am doing it here.

I tried what you have suggested and EF is inserting the properties from the Base class into the Base class table and from the derived class in to the corresponding table. Is there some way i can force it to insert all of the data into the derived table.

**Edit2** 
I figure out the answer with the help of google i need to use the MapInheritedProperties on the DbSet. 
Thank You for you help i will mark this answered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing that's wrong with your existing code is that `var repository = new Repository<typeof(base)>();` is not a valid form of a closed generic.

Given what you've shown, the design of your repository class is suspect - it would make more sense implemented as

```
public class Repository 
{
    private readonly TestContext _testContext;
    public Repository()
    {
        _testContext = new TestContext();
    }

    public void Add<T>(T input) where T : Base
    {
       var kew =  _testContext.Set<T>().Add(input);
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        _testContext.SaveChanges();
    }  
}
```

Which would allow your service implementation to be

```
public void Add(Base input)
{
    var repository = new Repository();
    repository.Add(input);
    repository.Save();
}
```

and work as expected.

Comment: My bad i have added that statement to indicate i want to initiate the repository of the type passed. But you are right its not valid code. I have tried what you have suggeted   var repository = new Repository<typeof(base)>();